# Odoo - How to find menu "action" name

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I would like to add "Products" directly to the top menu (without having to click on Inventory -> Products)

I have tried this:

```
<menuitem name= "Articles" id="product.menu_products_top_menu" action="product.product_normal_action_sell" sequence="4"/>
```

But "product.product_normal_action_sell" send me to "Products Variants" page which is not exactly what I want..

Where to find out the action name ?

Answer (score 0):

We can find the action name of a specific page by going to this page. On the Debug Mode -> Edit Action.

On the top we have "External ID" (which is corresponding to the action name) In my case: "product.product_template_action_product"